# Remove an Actor in Greenfoot if he´s on the top

Tags: java, greenfoot

I´m building my own Space Invaders in Java with Greenfoot and I have a Spaceship which shoots the Aliens, but the Bullets stop at the top of the map and stay there so I wrote this method which should remove a bullet if it hits the top of the  but it doesn't work. What´s the problem?

```
public void disappearIfOnTop() {
    Actor Bullet = getOneIntersectingObject(Actor.class);
    getY();

    if(getY() == 0) {
        World world;
        world = getWorld();
        world.removeObject(Bullet);
    }
}
```

Edit: they are getting removed if they hit another bullet which is stuck on the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getOneIntersectingObject()` returns a `null` if there is no **other** actor.

You might want to check this to be sure:

```java
public void disappearIfOnTop() {
    if (getY() == 0) {
        Actor bullet = getOneIntersectingObject(Actor.class);
        if (bullet == null) {
            setLocation(getX(), 50); // move down if no other is around
        } else {
            setLocation(getX(), 100); // move further down if another is around
        }
    }
}
```

If the method `getOneIntersectingObject()` returns a reference to an actor, your current method is removing **that** one, not the one who is at Y=0. (BTW, don't use variable names starting with uppercase letters. By convention, this is reserved for classes.)

You can simplify your method to:

```java
public void disappearIfOnTop() {
    if (getY() == 0) {
        getWorld().removeObject(this);
    }
}
```